# formatting date string in cakephp

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp, I've got a simple Users controller that corresponds to a users table. I have a created field in the table that I want to ouput on the view action using the niceShort() function. how do I use it in the view?

Current code is:

```
<p>Member since <?php echo $user['User']['created']?></p>
```

thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the controller you can include the build in time helper:

users_controllee.php:

```
var $helpers = array('Time');
```

In the view:

```
<p>Member since <?php echo $time->niceShort($user['User']['created']); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use built in php function date.

You can use it like this:

```
echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($user['User']['created']));
```

You can use any format you like for date formatting based on build in patterns.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

I think darko is right.

You can simply use PHP function date() to format your date in any type.

Example :

`$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($user['User']['created']));`

Here, strtotime() is the function of cakePHP to convert in datetime format.

Now you will have $date variable with a date formatted 'YYYY-mm-dd Hour:Minute:Second'.

For more option you can refer to PHP date manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope this will be helpful to you...

Comment: strtotime() is a php function and is not specific to cakephp only.

Answer (score 1):

Just as  point of reference the TimeHelper is CakePHP has a lot of nice stuff worth looking at
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html