# How to format the time in CakePHP?

Tags: datetime, cakephp, time, cakephp-1.3

I am using [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) 1.3 to write a application, and I create a `datetime` field in a database.

And I call it `echo $post['Post']['created'];` and I get something like `2011-07-03 00:00:00`.

What I would like is for it to look more like `Jan 1st 2008, 19:25`.

I see some documentation in *[7.12.1 Formatting](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1471/Formatting)* (CakePHP manual), but how do implement it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting date string in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520982/formatting-date-string-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to the format the date using `date()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
echo date('M j Y, h:i', strtotime($post['Post']['created']));
```

A better solution would be to create a helper. The best place to learn about these is the [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1095/Helpers).

Comment: i recommend using helpers and wrapper functions for this!

Comment: a bit too much for me right now, but if you have a tutorial or some code i can get, i will defiantly get a look on how i should do it the right way

Comment: Why isn't CakeTime mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

To do this using the built in cake `Time` helper, use this:

```
// controller:
$helpers = array('Time');
```

then in your view:

```
echo $this->Time->nice($post['Post']['created']);
// outputs Tue, Jan 1st 2008, 19:25".
```

If you're looking for performance (although negligible), you would be better off using `date` directly as the other poster suggests, without having the overhead of loading the `Time` helper.

But the helper is easier and quicker to implement, not to mention opens up the other helper functions, so it will depend on your needs obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it in Cake is to use the time helper. The previous post give the correct answer for CakePHP 2.x, you however asked for a solution for 1.3.
In your controller write:

```
var $helpers = array('Time');
```

In your view write:

```
echo $time->niceShort($post['Post']['created']);
```

This has worked for me the last 3 years.